# RecyclerView sets status for every tenth iconbutton not just for the pressed one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

my recyclerview contains image buttons which are star buttons. 
So when the user clicks on the imagebutton it must turn yellow.
When user clicks again on this image button, it must turn gray.
I save the position and the status of the buttons in a hashmap. The status can be -1 or 1.When it is 1, the buttons turns yellow when it is -1 the button turns grey.

The first thing i do is to set for every position in the onBindViewHolder method like a status for every position in a hashMap which is -1, what means that the button is not selected and grey.So the position is the key and the status (-1 or 1) is the value in the hashMap.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
      if(!hashMapStarButtons.containsKey(position)){
         hashMapStarButtons.put(position), -1);
      }
```

So when the image button is pressed, in the

> onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position)

method i take the position and i check the status and change it

```
holder.starButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
           int currentStat = hashMapStarButtons.get(position);   
           currentStat = currentStat * (-1);

           if(currentStat==1){
                holder.starButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(),android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on));
           }else{
                holder.starButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(),android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off));
           }
```

The problem here is that when i press a button which is on position 2, and the button must turn yellow because the status turns to 1, the recyclerView turns the buttons on position 12, 22, 32 into yellow too.
When i press the button on position 13 the color of the buttons on position 3, 23, 33 changes too.
Its realy weird. 
When i check all the values in the HAshMap only the status for the button which has been pressed has changed but not for others.

Here is my Holder class

```
class MyViewHolder extends   RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View view;

    // final
    private ImageButton starButton;
    private TextView movie;


    public MyViewHolder(View viewItem){
        super(viewItem);

        starButton = (ImageButton)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.starButton);
        movie = (TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.movie);

    }


    public void setMovie(String movie){
        movie.setText(movie);
    }

}
```

This is the adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private List<String> list;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMapStarButtons;

public MyAdapter(List<Movie> list){
    this.list = list;
    hashMapStarButtons = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    // Hole das Layout für die Row
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_row, parent, false));
}

// onBindViewHolder is called for every single item in the RecyclerView
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
    Movie movie = list.get(position);
    holder.setMovie(movie.getMovie());

    if(!hashMapStarButtons.containsKey(position)){
        hashMapStarButtons.put(position, -1);
    }

    holder.starButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int currentStat = hashMapStarButtons.get(position);
            currentStat = currentStat * (-1);

            if(currentStat==1){
                holder.starButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(),android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on));
            }else{
                holder.starButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(),android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off));
            }



        }
    });

}
```

}

here is my activity from where iam loading the data from firebase

```
public class MyActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mStatusDB;

// everything for RecyclerView
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<String> list;
private MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mymovies);

    mStatusDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("movies");

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.movRecylerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    getList();

    adapter = new MyAdapter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void getList(){
    mStatusDB.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Movie movie = new Movie();

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                String key = snapshot.getKey();
                String mov = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                movie.setMovie(value);
            }

            list.add(movie);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Here you can see the problem only with ten rows:

[image]

Please help me where the problem is?
it is not in the hashmap in the statuses.
In the Picture the status for the row 10 would be -1 what means that the button should be gray.

Comment: hi look my answer at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342165/recycler-view-wrongly-selecting-view-item-while-performing-multi-select/45342598#45342598

Comment: I think it is caused by first line in `onBindViewHolder()` try to call `list.get(position)` every time instead of setting that static value to `Movie movie` .

Comment: it happen because u not saving the state of selected item and recylerview recycle the position of list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't check inside the `OnBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position)` which is the state of the item at the position `position`. Looking at the code, you are checking it only inside the OnClickListener().

What is happening in you code is that the view of item 1 is recycled and used to put item 10, but the star in the view was colored in yellow and in your OnBindViewHolder you are not resetting its color to white.

This is my suggestion:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
    Movie movie = list.get(position);
    holder.setMovie(movie.getMovie());

    if(!hashMapStarButtons.containsKey(position)){
        hashMapStarButtons.put(position, -1);
    }
    if(hashMapStarButtons.get(position)==-1){
        holder.starButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(),android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off));
    } else {
         holder.starButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(),android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on));
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recylerview recycles or Binds the same view after every 9 items. So if the 1st item is changed it will reflect or reuse the same view after 9th item.

So work around is to make use of `setItemViewCacheSize()` on recylerview

```
public void setItemViewCacheSize(int size)
```

> Set the number of offscreen views to retain before adding them to the potentially shared recycled view pool.
>   The offscreen view cache stays aware of changes in the attached adapter, allowing a LayoutManager to reuse those views unmodified without needing to return to the adapter to rebind them.

Make changes here

```
 list = new ArrayList<>();
    getList();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(list);
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(list.size());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

By doing this it will not recycle the same view. This may look simple but it does the work. Give a try.